# Castear dato Android

Tags: android, android-studio, jsoup

la cosa es que consigo traer un dato que quiero desde internet pero viene acompañado de una etiqueta que me gustaría remover. Obtengo los datos desde aquí:

```
<a style="display: block;" class="btn-collapse" onclick="collapseChapter('collapsible490362')" role="button">
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-fw"></i> 
  Capítulo 120.00
</a>
```

Lo que me interesa de ahí es el dato: **Capítulo 120.00**. El problema es que en mi aplicación esto se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como traigo el dato:

```
            for (Element e1 : data) {
                for(Element e2 : dataDos){
                    String numeroCap = e1.select("a").html();//es este
                    String urlManga = e2.select("a").attr("href");
                    tmoDatosSeleccions.add(new TMODatosSeleccion(numeroCap, urlManga));
                }
            }
```

De manera que eso se imprime así:

```
<i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-fw"></i> Capítulo 120.00
```

Y, como dije, solo quiero que se vea el: **Capítulo 120.00**

¿Alguien sabe como lo puedo arreglar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes

**Eliminar el contenido HTML en String**

de esta forma:

```
String resultado = "<i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-fw"></i> Capítulo 120.00";
resultado = resultado .replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "").trim();
```

para obtener únicamente

```
Capítulo 120.00
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido :) ¿Podrías ver mi pregunta sobre el error en mi `AsyncTask`?

Answer (score 1):

intenta poner `/*` y al final `*/` se veria asi

```
/*<i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-fw"></i>*/ Capítulo 120.00
```

Comment: Creo que me expliqué mal, pues esto `<i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-fw"></i> Capítulo 120.00` viene al momento de parsear los datos de internet. Por ende, no puedo hacer eso que dices